# Perforce recommended way to work on a task while keeping stable state

Tags: perforce

Recently I started working at a new place and my company uses Perforce as their source control.

From what I saw, my team members are working on a task and when they finish the task they just submit the files. In case they need to stop working on the current task and move to another one, they shelve the files and move to the different task. This means, there is a shelve per task, but there is no way to view local history of things that were done as part of the task. This results large changes at every submit, and it is not possible to easily return to a working state as part of the current task.

In the past, I have been working with git. With git, I would commit **very** often and I was able to easily view the history of the changes I have done, even in the short term.
For example, before renaming a variable I would always commit, and then if something gets messed up, I would just revert it without even thinking and trying to dive into debugging of what is wrong. As well, when developing a feature and having basic things that work, I would commit so I would just be able to easily return to that state.

What I started to do is manually copy the files I am working on to a local git repo and then commit things over there, and then copy them back to perforce before submitting them. This is definitely a bad idea.

I am aware to the fact the git and perforce are fundamentally different, and I wanted to know what is the recommended way to work when working on a large task at perforce without accidentally destroying my work during the development.

I am working on a gigantic project, and working with git-p4 and syncing all the changes is impossible. As well, I tried to look at: [Perforce equivalent of git local commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28619344/perforce-equivalent-of-git-local-commit) but it still means there is a shelve saved for each state I want to save, which is not very convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of doing this in Perforce is to use a branch; unlike shelves, branches maintain full version history of everything.  There are three basic approaches to consider:

- Create a single personal dev branch that you stabilize all your changes in before merging them back to the mainline branch.  After everything has been stabilized and merged from your dev branch to the mainline, your dev branch can be updated to the latest mainline state and you have a "clean" basis for your next batch of changes.
- Create a new task branch (or `task` stream if you're using streams) per major change.  This can be a bit heavyweight if you have a lot of files in a "classic" branching model, but if you're using task streams, you can `unload` the task stream after the task is done to prune the unchanged branched files from the active depot history (similar to what happens when you squash a branch in git).
- Create a personal server via `p4 clone`.  This is the most git-like model -- you instantiate an entire new server on your local machine, where you can create all the branches you want with no impact on the shared server.  When your changes are ready, you `p4 push` them back to the shared server.  `p4 fetch` is used to pull newer changes from the shared server and "rebase" your local changes onto them if required.

I've usually opted for the first approach; the main potential drawback to it is that if you have multiple major destabilizing changes in flight at the same time, it's hard to isolate them from each other in a single branch, but in practice this is a situation that hasn't come up very often for me.